# Two domains - single install - Live Preview works only on one

Tags: live-preview, multi-domain, multi-site

I have a multi-site setup on two different domains (actually subdomains) with a single Craft install. I have modified `config/general.php` file to make it work on both the subdomains. Each domain has different template set completely independent of each other. However, Live Preview will work on entries created for only one sub-domain (one that is specified in the control panel). The option is not available for the other subdomain. This is because the public link for the entries corresponding to second subdomain is being parsed as those belonging to the first subdomain. Obviously those links are giving 404 error and hence the Live Preview button is not active.

Is there a way to tell craft that certain entries belong to a specific subdomain?

Comment: I created a 301 directives on nginx so that the url button (globe icon) redirects to correct subdomains. But Live Preview button is still not showing up for one subdomain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get Live Preview to work across different subdomains on a single install, you'll need to setup a few extra things as outlined in this support article: https://craftcms.com/support/cross-domain-live-preview